# JPanel doesnt allow positioning component

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtabbedpane

So I have created 2 `JFrames`

[image: Person]

[image: Work Detail]

But then I realized 2 `JFrames` is not a good idea.So I added `JTabbedPane` and then tried adding as different tabs in form of `'JPanel`. But I cant position the components the way I did in `Jframe` and it looks like this.

[image: Main Menu]

But I want it to be like this

[image: Expected Main Menu]

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a proper layout mechanism for your JPanel? E.g. [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a working example, it appears you've left the default layout for the `JPanel` (which is a `FlowLayout`).

Start by creating a custom panel for each of your views, it will make it easier to manage and the apply them to the `JTabbedPane`.

For your immeditate layout issue, I'd recommend `GridBagLayout` for its power and flexibility...

[image: Layout][image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();
                tp.add("Person", new JPanel());
                tp.add("Work Detail", new TestPane());

                frame.add(tp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField name;
        private JTextField serial;
        private JTextField id;
        private JTextField email;

        private JComboBox level;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

            add(new JLabel("Name"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            add(new JLabel("Sr No"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("ID"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            add(new JLabel("Email ID"), gbc);

            name = new JTextField(10);
            serial = new JTextField(10);
            id = new JTextField(10);
            email = new JTextField(10);

            level = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Manager", "Eng Lead", "Eng Designer", "Jr Designer"});

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(name, gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            add(serial, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(id, gbc);
            gbc.gridx += 2;
            add(email, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(level, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(new JButton("Save"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I used `GridBagLayout ` as you suggested but the problem here is that width of a column below a component has to be same as the above.How can I change that?

Comment: Congrats, MadProgrammer, on reaching 200K :-) @livinggourmand: Please try, `GridBagConstraints` like `gridwidth/gridheight` to make the column width more or less.

Comment: @nIcE cOw  Once I set column width for a row, the column below that row is not accepting any other value for width

Comment: @MadProgrammer I used `AbsoluteLayout` on `JPanel` and it works, is that fine? With `GridBagLayout`  i was having issues.

Comment: What do you mean by "column below component has to be same as above"?  Other then the combobox, they are for the other four components. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @MadProgrammer http://i.stack.imgur.com/99OM5.jpg I added a `JTextField` but it is automatically taking all the the space available and I am unable to resize by dragging(Using Windows Builder).Also when I add anything below this row, it takes same size as above.

Comment: Don't use window builders; weightx, gridwidth and fill will effect a components horizontal width

Comment: @livinggourmand: Here do try this another example, using `GridBagLayout`, that I am posting as an answer, for sometime. `GridBagLayout` is way too powerful, just you not using it in the right sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is one I used recently. Just use the layout you want (MigLayout was my choice here).

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

JPanel pnlOne = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab One Name", null, pnlOne, null);
pnlOne.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[644.00,grow][50px:n,grow][]","[grow][]"));

JPanel pnlTwo = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.addTab("Tab Two Name", null, pnlTwo, null);
pnlTwo.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][]", "[grow][]"));
```